# Expand Column List in OpenEdge datagrip

Tags: openedge, datagrip

I have a connection to an OpenEdge database using Datagrip. The intelisense seems very minimal. At a minimum I would like to be able to expand the column list from the star. I know it can work because I have set up other systems that use OpenEdge and JetBrains. It there some setting or something I am missing to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have a list of columns under table node in database explorer?

Comment: Yes I do have the list of columns. And the table does autocomplete. just not the fields

Comment: Could you file an issue in [DataGrip bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE)?